# C# code executed successfully with SQL but when checked in Database they are still showing null values

Tags: c#, sql

**My data has to be saved from various text boxes but what happened is that when i try to save there is no error message but the problem for me is that data is not getting posted to SQL database,
all of its values are showing null when checked in SQL tables

My Save button function is as follows**

```
 private void btnsavebill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        transactionBLL transaction = new transactionBLL();
        transaction.type = lblpurchasehead.Text;

        //get the ID of the dealer or customer HEre
        // get the name of the dealer or custoemr name
        string deacustname = txtdlrname.Text;
        dealerBLL dc = dcdal.getdeacustIDfromName(deacustname);

        transaction.date_cust_id = dc.id;
        transaction.grandtotal = Math.Round(decimal.Parse(txtgrandtotal.Text), 2);
        transaction.transaction_date = DateTime.Now;
        transaction.tax = decimal.Parse(txtgstper.Text);
        transaction.discount = decimal.Parse(txtDiscountbill.Text);

        //get user name of logged in user name
        string username = frmLogin.loggedIn;
        userBLL u = udal.GetIDFromUsername(username);

        transaction.added_by = u.id;
        transaction.transactiondetail = transactionDT;

        // creating a boolean variable and set value to false
        bool success = false;

        //Actual cocde to insert trans and trans DT

        using TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope();
        {
            int transactionId = -1;

            bool w = tdal.Insert_Transaction(transaction, out transactionId);


            //use for loop to insert transaction details

            for (int i = 0;i<transactionDT.Rows.Count;i++)
            {
                //get all the details of products
                transactiondetailBLL transactiondetail = new transactiondetailBLL();

                //get the product name and convert it into ID
                string ProductName = transactionDT.Rows[i][0].ToString();

                productsBLL p = pdal.getproductsIDfromName(ProductName);
                
                transactiondetail.product_int = p.id;
                transactiondetail.rate = decimal.Parse(transactionDT.Rows[i][1].ToString());
                transactiondetail.qty = decimal.Parse(transactionDT.Rows[i][2].ToString());
                transactiondetail.total = Math.Round(decimal.Parse(transactionDT.Rows[i][3].ToString()), 2);
                transactiondetail.dec_cust_id = dc.id;
                transactiondetail.added_date = DateTime.Now;
                transactiondetail.added_by = u.id;

                //Insert transaction Detail inside our Database
                bool y = tddal.InsertTransactionDetail(transactiondetail);
                success = w && y;
            }
            if (success == true)
            {
                //transaction complete
                MessageBox.Show("Transaction completed successfully to details table");
                //clear data grid view
                dgvaddprodforbill.DataSource = null;
                dgvaddprodforbill.Rows.Clear();

                //clear all other values

                txtdlrSearch.Text = "";
                txtdlremail.Text = "";
                txtdlrname.Text = "";
                txtdlrcontact.Text = "";
                txtdlraddress.Text = "";
                txtproductsearch.Text = "";
                txtproname.Text = "";
                txtproinventory.Text = "";
                txtproprice.Text = "";
                txtproqty.Text = "";
                txtsubtotal.Text = "0";
                txtDiscountbill.Text = "0";
                txtgstper.Text = "0";
                txtgrandtotal.Text = "0";
                txtpaidamount.Text = "0";



            }
            else
            {
                //transaction failed
                MessageBox.Show("Transaction completed failed to details table");
            }
```

**my data access layer is also as follows**

```
#region Insert Transaction MEthod

    public  bool  Insert_Transaction(transactionBLL t, out int transactionID)
    {
        bool issucess = false;

        transactionID = -1;

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(myconnstring);


        try
        {
            //sql query to insert transactions
         
            string sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_transaction (type, date_cust_id, grandtotal, transaction_date, tax, discount, added_by) VALUES (@type, @date_cust_id, @grandtotal, @transaction_date, @tax, @discount, @added_by);SELECT @@IDENTITY;";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", t.type);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date_cust_id", t.date_cust_id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grandtotal", t.grandtotal);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transaction_date", t.transaction_date);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tax", t.tax);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@discount", t.discount);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("added_by", t.added_by);

            connection.Open();

            object o = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            
            //if the query is executed successfully then the value will not be null or vice versa

            if (o!=null)
            {
                transactionID = int.Parse(o.ToString());
                issucess = true;
                
            }
            else
            {
                issucess = false;
            }
            }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }

        return issucess;
    }

    #endregion
```

**Please find a way cause i cannot i am a person who does not have any coding backgroung tins is my first try by watching various youtube videos and tutorials i dont wanna be stuck due to my mistake**

Comment: Why did you change to ExecuteScalar?  Execute Scalar only updates one column.  Go back to original code I gave you.

Comment: Did you commit your database transaction? By the way, [AddWithValue is evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: @jdweng thanku for ur time but i did not receive any code  in fact the person i learned is from Vijay thappa a youtuber from nepal,

Comment: @mason yes i did , by using 'cmd' and Sql string

Comment: @jdweng What makes you think ExecuteScalar only updates one column? It only *returns* one value. Do you see the difference?

Comment: Sorry : I've been helping with this link which is very similar to yours (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68123578/insert-data-into-an-empty-sql-database-table-using-wpf?force_isolation=true).  Try using like my last comment on link : int rowsChanged = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: This code seems correct at first glance. Please execute it line per line and check the value of each SQL parameter value passed in your C# code. Please also double check the record in de SQL table after execution.

Comment: SIde notes.  (1) please research and learn and apply "layered design".   at the LEAST, you should probably have 3 layers.  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1492b1/understanding-multilayered-architecture-in-net/. you should NEVER EVER EVER see "button1_click" and "sqlcommand" in the same block of code. (2) your method should not return "bool", this is a "status code".  please research and learn and apply : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/exception-throwing